# Display in view for a specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, conditional-statements

I m working on app and i have a question for you. I m trying to display field for a specific value. I have 2 value "oui" and "non". I m done an if condition but doesn't work, value "non" is always display. I don't want to display this.

> ```
> My value in db
> Plage = oui
> Etang = oui
> Montagne = oui
> Riviere = non
> ```

```
<% @camping.situations.each do |situation| %>
        <% if situation.plage == "oui" || situation.etang == "oui" || situation.montagne == "oui" || situation.riviere == "oui"  %>
        <p> Plage: <%=situation.plage %> à <%=situation.distanceplage%> km</p>
        <p> Etang: <%=situation.etang%></p>
        <p> Montagne: <%=situation.montagne %></p>
        <p> Rivière: <%=situation.riviere%></p>
        <% else %>

        <%end%>

      <%end%>
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Your 'if' check will evaluate to TRUE when any of you variables are equivalent to "oui".

In your exmple, Plage is == "oui". This means that your IF check will ignore the next checks for the other variables because you are using OR checks. This is called Short Circuiting (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) in programming.

Consider using an "&&" statement instead of "||". That way when any one of us your variables is "non", it won't display that view.

Comment: Nothing will display due to the fact that one of your variables is not equal to "oui". When you chain all of your comparisons with "&&", all comparisons must be true.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand... what I need to write for my condition ?

Comment: You need multiple IF checks for each variable.